# How to calculate the 6 Bit CRC using the c programming lanuguage?

Tags: crc

I'm using Encoder where I'm getting the 0 to 24 bits, from which 0 to 5 bits are CRC bits. Can anyone help me to understand how to calculate the CRC code for those 6 bits?

[image: layout of transmitted bits for three encoder models]
[image: linear feedback shift register schematic for the CRC]

Comment: I see five different 6-bit CRCs [here](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.6), and yours might be yet another one. You'd need to provide more information on the definition of the CRC you need from the documentation you are looking at. Perhaps on page 23 looking at the contents on the left.

Comment: @MarkAdler -  I found the document, it is X^6 + x + 1, and is a left shifting CRC, based on the diagram. The diagram image is  a mirrored right shifting LFSR, with x^0 on the left and x^5 on the right, and a comment that input data is MSB first, so it's a left shifting CRC. I didn't find what the initial value for CRC is, but I may have just missed it.  [link to asx36.pdf](http://www.lika.pl/pliki_do_pobrania/MAN%20ASx36%20SSI_I7%20E%20(2).pdf#page=22).

Comment: @omkardixit Can you provide any examples of single cycle data from the device?

Comment: @MarkAdler problem solved thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an example, I can't be sure, but this will compute the CRC as described, assuming that the initial values of the flip flops are zero.

```
unsigned crc6biss(uint32_t data, unsigned bits) {
    while (bits--)
        data = data & 0x80000000 ? (data << 1) ^ 0x0c000000 : data << 1;
    return ~data >> 26;
}
```

Here `data` are your data bits, but, very importantly, shifted up in the 32-bit word so that the most significant bit of the data is the most significant bit of `data`. `bits` is how many bits are to be processed. So the data bits are the bits `32-bits`..`31` of `data`. The remaining bits are zeros. The 6-bit CRC is returned in the least significant six bits of the return value.

From your documentation, `bits` would be 18, 19, or 21.